# Creating HTML email from UITextField text

Tags: ios, objective-c, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I'm a novice and recreational programmer. I am trying to create an app for iOS that populates the text from my UITextFields. I have 3 the actionField, impactField, and result Field. I'd like for each to have their own line, if possible.

I looked at a similar answer, but it was not any help for me. Does anyone have any tutorials or advice?

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap: (id)sender {
    [self.actionField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.impactField resignFirstResponder];
    [self.resultField resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)sendBullet:(id)sender {
    NSString *emailTitle = @"Email";
    NSString *messageBody = @"Title";
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"email"];

    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:emailTitle];
    [mc setMessageBody:messageBody isHTML:NO];
    [mc setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: You need to build up `messageBody` with the text of the text fields.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy. (Thank you for correcting the look of my code.  It didn't look all jumbled when I pasted it in.

Comment: Is there an example how to put the UITextView in, without having to type anything in as a string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is build a string from the text fields:

```
NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Action: %@\nImpact: %@\nResult: %@", self.actionField.text, self.impactField.text, self.resultField.text];
```

Update the format string as needed. What I present here is just one example.

The `\n` is a special value in a string that means "newline". This means the string I show will consist of three lines of text.

Comment: rmaddy, thank you for that!  Being a novice, I didn't know how to apply that.  I have been using quite a bit of tutorial help!

Answer (score 2):

MHinton,

Before you proceed, you should take a look at HTML syntax, there are hundreds of thousands of tutorials out there since this has been around for decades. It's fairly easy to pick up. You can start [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/html/)

**NOTE** It's best to test HTML emails on a device as the simulator can be kind of wonky with the `MFMailComposeViewController`

Secondly, grabbing the text from a text view or other forms of strings is fairly easy, again, thousands of tutorials out there. Specifically for Obj C you do it as follows :

1) Create an outlet for your textfields

```
@interface YourViewController: UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *actionField
@end
```

2) Then you can reference it anywhere in your implementation file (.m) like this :

```
NSString *emailMessageBody = self.actionField.text;
```

**DISPLAYING TEXT IN HTML FORMAT FOR EMAILS**

Creating an HTML formatted email is relatively easy as long as you spend about 15 minutes learning HTML syntax.

If you want to insert your UITextFields in different lines you implement the HTML equivalent to line break (or pressing the enter button): `<br>`

So an example string to pass in the `MFMailComposeViewController` will look like this:

```
NSString *emailMessageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The retrieved text from actionField is : <br><strong><font color=\"red\">'%@'</font><br></strong><br> The retrieved text from impactField is : <br>%@<br> The retrieved text from resultField is : <br>%@<br>", self.actionField.text, self.impactField.text, self.resultField.text];
```

Your options are limitless here, as long as you know HTML syntax. *So whats going on here?*

- `<br>` creates the line break
- `<strong>` creates a bold style text and to end the format you place `</strong>` after the last word you want bold faced
- `<font>` self explanatory; you have to end this style format as well.

You call it in the `MFMailComposeViewController` per usual, however you must explicitly set the email to HTML so all the HTML tags can be stripped from formatting and so it doesn't display it as plain text.

```
[mc setMessageBody:emailMessageBody isHTML:YES];
```

---

Other commonly used HTML tags are :

- `<style>` for formatting
- `<p>` for paragraphs
- `<h1>` for headers
- `<mark>` for highlighting
- `<small>` for small text
- `<i>` or `<em>` for italics or emphasized

Refer to the link above for more HTML tags

---

**SWIFT SYNTAX**

```
 var emailMessageBody = NSString(format:"The retrieved text from actionField is : <br><strong><font color=\"red\">'%@'</font><br></strong><br> The retrieved text from impactField is : <br>%@<br> The retrieved text from resultField is : <br>%@<br>", actionField.text, impactField.text, resultField.text) as String
 mailComposerVC.setMessageBody(emailMessageBody, isHTML: true)
```

Comment: Kudos for a thorough answer :)

Comment: Thank you for this, soulshined. I have been using apps like app coda to learn a bit about HTML. This will go along way to helping me out.